# get 4 days back data from today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MSSQL 2017 express. What i want is i want to return 4 days back data from todays date where IsaAtive is 1. I already with less then greater then sign bellow but this not works at all. Any one can fix my query so it will return is data 4 days back from today? Any example?

SQL:

```
Select * 
From MyTableName 
Where CheckedDate < '2018-09-10 00:00:00.000' AND IsActive = '1'
```

Comment: Something like `CheckedDate < DATEADD(day, -4, CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())) AND IsActive='1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query: using DATEADD(day, -4,getdate()) and getdate()

```
Select * 
From MyTableName 
Where CheckedDate >= DATEADD(day, -4, getdate()) and 
      CheckedDate < getdate() AND IsActive = '1'
```